# C# client.Receive not working ( on windows 8.1 ?)

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, windows-8.1

I recently upgraded my OS to windows 8.1.

I'm currently developping an application capable of receiving UDP packets from a DAQ.
But since i upgraded to Windows 8, The client.receive(cardIp) method return null instead of the byte array of the packet and raise the exception :

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

I checked on wireshark and the packet are received by the network interface. 
I only changed OS since the last time it worked.

Thank you.

PS : my english might not be very good, it's not my native langage.

PS2: Feel free to ask more details.

Answer (score 0):

Okay nevermind i found the problem.

I didn't reset my firewall's rules since i formated my PC and it was blocking the traffic.
now it works.